# File management iOS

Tags: ios

I am creating a static library for iOS which reads data from files which have to be present in the system (I am not downloading them when the application runs) and do some calculations and return the results.
I will need to ship the files along the application. So my questions are below

1. How to include input files in the project so that they get copied along with the application.
2. How to read from the files when the application is running.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to include input files in the project so that they get copied along with the application.

Copy them into the app's bundle directory.

> How to read from the files when the application is running.

Now that's broad enough a question. Maybe you're looking for the [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [NSFileHandle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilehandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSData](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdata_Class/Reference/Reference.html) classes.